# Using str.replace for multiple words

Tags: javascript, string, replace, str-replace

I am creating a work tool for notepad abbreviations. As the company I work for is strict about downloading any external tools I've resorted to using Javascript and HTML built on notepad.

I've been able to replace single words such as when I type "Vacancy" it returns "VAC". Or when typing "Payment" it returns "PYMT". My issue is trying to replace multiple words into 1 small abbreviation. For instance "Follow Up" I want to return "F/U". With the spaces I'm finding it is not working.

Tried multiple ways but unable to figure this out.

Here is the code snippet that I've used

```
function myFunction() {

var str = document.getElementById("demo").value; 
var mapObj = {
   Payment:"PYMT",
   Vacancy:"VAC", 
str = str.replace(/Payment|Vacancy, fucntion(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});
alert(str);
  document.getElementById("demo").value = res;
}
```

What I would like to do is add my mabObj
so it would read

```
function myFunction() {

var str = document.getElementById("demo").value; 
var mapObj = {
Follow Up:"F/U"
str = str.replace(/Follow Up|, fucntion(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});
alert(str);
  document.getElementById("demo").value = res;
}
```

Comment: Your code have a lot of syntax errors. However, try using quotes in your object definition, like `var mapObj = {"Follow Up":"F/U" }`. Then you can do: `str = str.replace(/Follow Up/, function(matched) {return mapObj[matched];});`

Comment: Lots of typos. Missing `/` at the end of the first regexp, you misspelled `function` as `fucntion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript objects can have properties with spaces in them, but in order to do so, the property name needs to have quotes around it.

That said, I would suggest using a `Map` in this case, as it will allow you to match any string without worrying about naming collisions with properties from the object's prototype.

```
const abbreviation = new Map([
    ['Follow Up', 'F/U'],
    ['Payment', 'PYMT'],
    ['Vacancy', 'VAC']
]);
const input = 'Payment noise Vacancy noise Follow Up noise Vacancy';
const pattern = new RegExp(Array.from(abbreviation.keys()).join('|'),'g');
const result = input.replace(pattern, (matched) => {
    return abbreviation.get(matched) || matched;
});
console.log(result);  // 'PYMT noise VAC noise F/U noise VAC'
```

Comment: `new RegExp(Array.from(abbreviation.keys()).join('|'),'g')` if you're generating a regex dynamically from the names, then you have to make sure they are escaped, otherwise `"Mr."` might match `"Mrs"`, for example.

Comment: True, @VLAZ. Escaping regex is non-trivial, so instead I've added `|| matched` to my answer, in the replacer function. That ensures that only exact matches have any effect. It will cause `Mrs` to be returned instead of `undefined` when `Mr.` matches it and thus that part of the string will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

To include a key with a space in an object you can put it in brackets like `{["Follow Up"]: "F/U"}`

```js
function replaceKeyWords(str) {
  var mapObj = {
     Payment:"PYMT",
     Vacancy:"VAC",
     ["Follow Up"]:"F/U",
  };
  str = str.replace(/(Payment|Vacancy|Follow Up)/, function(matched){
    return mapObj[matched];
  });
  return str;
}

console.log(replaceKeyWords("Payment"));
console.log(replaceKeyWords("Vacancy"));
console.log(replaceKeyWords("Follow Up"));
```

Comment: You don't need brackets, only quotes. The brackets are for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) but you are using a static string, so there is no need for evaluation.

Comment: Oh interesting. Thanks for the note.